# Handling multiple Clients over TCP

Tags: sockets, go

Okay, I just started learning golang and I like it so far. However I don't find their documentation good for go starters, Here is my problem.
I wanted to write little server program that accepts connections and writes something to the client. No problem doing that so far.

However as soon as the thing get a real functionality, I need to be able to handle multiple clients, which I though would also be a good exercise for goroutines.

```
listener, error := net.Listen("tcp", remote)
con, error := listener.Accept()
go handleClient(&con);
func handleClient(con *net.Conn) {
```

I've cut most of the code out. The problem is, no matter what I try, I can't pass `con`.

```
con.RemoteAddr undefined (type *net.Conn has no field or method RemoteAddr)
```

(found that in this example: http://raycompstuff.blogspot.com/2009/12/simpler-chat-server-and-client-in.html).
So i tried looking at the documentation, but it just gave me the source of the net package.
Read trough the source, and figured it should be

```
undefined: TCPConn
```

How can I pass the connection of a client to a goroutine, so i can handle multiple clients at once?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.
There is some guy who actually already wrote what I wanted to write in go.
https://github.com/dustin/gomemcached/blob/master/mc_conn_handler.go

```
go handleClient(con);
func handleClient(con net.Conn) {
```

Comment: Should we use con *net.Conn or con net.Cnnn?

Comment: The link is gone.